# How are sitemap files automatically updated?

Tags: php, html, xml, sitemap

How are sitemap files are automatically updated?

I have a website which is updated 4-5 times a day. I have added the sitemap in xml. How does the sitemap file update automatically? Is there any option while creating the sitemap?

Comment: Dynamically generate the sitemap  somehow.

Comment: call your generating sitemap functionallity with `crontab` or trigger it after some update actions

Comment: Generally, you would update it in the same way that you add new pages to the site. We've no idea what you are doing to add new pages though, which makes this too broad to really answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your url from `sitemap.xml` to `sitemap.php` (.htaccess on apache or your config file on nginx).
Then in your PHP file you can query the database for all pages and return as XML format using the header:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

Loop through all the pages and print the relevant sitemap.